# It 145 project 2

Tags: java, switch-statement, user-input

> I'm having trouble getting the userInput to work for case 4 and onwards in the printAnimals() at the very bottom. It like the userInput variable is not being able to be accessed. After the user types 4 it should print the dogList then return back to the menu. But instead I just get errors when passing userInput into printAnimals at case 4 and at the if statement within printAnimals();

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
    private static ArrayList<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
    //Add a monkey Array list
    private static ArrayList<Monkey> monkeyList = new ArrayList<Monkey>();
    //This is a scanner to get user input
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Initialize variables 
        String userInput;
        
        initializeDogList();
        initializeMonkeyList();

       //Do-While loop to access menu
       do{
           //Display the menu
           displayMenu();
           //Get the user input 
           userInput = scanner.nextLine();
           //Switch through each option the user can choose
           switch(userInput) {
                case "1":
                    intakeNewDog(scanner);
                case "2":
                    intakeNewMonkey(scanner);
                case "3":
                    reserveAnimal(scanner);
                case "4":
                    printAnimals(userInput);
                case "5":
                    printAnimals(userInput);
                case "6":
                    printAnimals();
                case "q":
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again. Enter 1-6 or q to quit.");
           }
        }while(!userInput.equals("q"));

    }

    // This method prints the menu options
    public static void displayMenu() {
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\tRescue Animal System Menu");
        System.out.println("[1] Intake a new dog");
        System.out.println("[2] Intake a new monkey");
        System.out.println("[3] Reserve an animal");
        System.out.println("[4] Print a list of all dogs");
        System.out.println("[5] Print a list of all monkeys");
        System.out.println("[6] Print a list of all animals that are not reserved");
        System.out.println("[q] Quit application");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter a menu selection");
    }
    

    // Adds dogs to a list for testing
    public static void initializeDogList() {
        Dog dog1 = new Dog("Spot", "German Shepherd", "male", "1", "25.6", "05-12-2019", "United States", "intake", false, "United States");
        Dog dog2 = new Dog("Rex", "Great Dane", "male", "3", "35.2", "02-03-2020", "United States", "Phase I", false, "United States");
        Dog dog3 = new Dog("Bella", "Chihuahua", "female", "4", "25.6", "12-12-2019", "Canada", "in service", true, "Canada");

        dogList.add(dog1);
        dogList.add(dog2);
        dogList.add(dog3);
    }


    // Adds monkeys to a list for testing
    //Optional for testing
    public static void initializeMonkeyList() {
        Monkey monkeyOne = new Monkey("DK", "3", "7", "15", "Guenon", "male", "4", "15", "4-1-22", "Japan", "intake", true, "USA");
        //Adds a new monkey to the ArrayList
        monkeyList.add(monkeyOne);

    }


    // Complete the intakeNewDog method
    // The input validation to check that the dog is not already in the list
    // is done for you
    public static void intakeNewDog(Scanner scanner) {
        // Add the code to instantiate a new dog and add it to the appropriate list
        System.out.println("What is the dog's name?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
       
        String gender;
        do {
              System.out.println("What is the dog's gender?");
              gender = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        }while (!gender.equals("male") && !gender.equals("female")); 
        
        
        System.out.println("What is the dog's age?");
        String age = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("What is the dog's weight?");
        String weight = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("When was the dog's acquired?");
        String acquisitionDate = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Where was the dog acquired?");
        String acquisitionCountry = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("What is the dog training status?");
        String trainingStatus = scanner.nextLine();
        
        
        System.out.println("In what country is the dog in service?");
        String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Is this dog reserved? True or False.");
        String reservedSpot;
        reservedSpot = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("reservedString: " + reservedSpot);
        boolean reserved;
        for(Dog dog: dogList) {
            if(dog.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                System.out.println("\n\nThis dog is already in our system\n\n");
                return; //returns to menu
            }
            if(!"true".equals(reservedSpot) && !"false".equals(reservedSpot)) {
                System.out.println("Re-input reservation status.");
                reservedSpot = scanner.nextLine();
             }
             
        }
        reserved = "true".equals(reservedSpot.toLowerCase());
        //This creates a new dog from user input 
       Dog dog = new Dog(name, gender, age, weight, acquisitionDate, acquisitionCountry,trainingStatus ,inServiceCountry, reserved, inServiceCountry);
        
       //Print out after the dog has been added to the system 
       System.out.println("The dog has successfully been added to our system.");
        //This adds the dog to the arrayList called dogList
        dogList.add(dog);
      //Returns back to menu
        return;
        
    }


        // Completed intakeNewMonkey
    //Instantiate and add the new monkey to the appropriate list
    //Made sure there could be no repeat of Monkeys
        public static void intakeNewMonkey(Scanner scanner) {
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's name");
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            for(Monkey monkey: monkeyList) {
                if(monkey.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    System.out.println("\n\nThis monkey is already in our system.\n\n");
                    return; //returns to menu
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's tail lenght?");
            String tailLength = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's height?");
            String height = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's body Length?");
            String bodyLength = scanner.nextLine();
            
            //Do while loop to get the monkey species
            String species;
            do {
                System.out.println("What is the monkey's species?");
                System.out.println("Species:Capuchin, Guenon, Macaque, Marmose, Squirrel monkey, Tamarin");
                species = scanner.nextLine();
            }while(!"Capuchin".equals(species) && !"Guenon".equals(species) && !"Macaque".equals(species) && !"Marmose".equals(species) &&
                    !"Squirrel monkey".equals(species) && !"Tamarin".equals(species));
            
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's gender?");
            String gender = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's age?");
            String age = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's weight?");
            String weight = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("When was the monkey's acquired?");
            String acquisitionDate = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("Where was the monkey acquired?");
            String acquisitionCountry = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey training status?");
            String trainingStatus = scanner.nextLine();
            
            String reservedString;
            System.out.println("Is this monkey reserved? True or False.");
            
            reservedString = scanner.nextLine();
            
            while (!reservedString.equalsIgnoreCase("true") && !reservedString.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                System.out.println("Re-input reservation status.");
                reservedString = scanner.nextLine();
            }
            boolean reserved = "true".equals(reservedString.toLowerCase());
     
            
            System.out.println("In what country is the monkey in service?");
            String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
            
            //This creates a new monkey from user input 
            Monkey monkey = new Monkey(name, tailLength, height, bodyLength, species,
                    gender ,age, weight, acquisitionDate, acquisitionCountry,trainingStatus ,reserved, inServiceCountry);
            
            //This adds the monkey to the arrayList called monkeyList
            monkeyList.add(monkey);
            //Print out after the monkey has been added to the system 
            System.out.println("The monkey has successfully been added to our system.");
            return;
        }

        // Complete reserveAnimal
        // You will need to find the animal by animal type and in service country
        public static void reserveAnimal(Scanner scanner) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a animal type.");
            String animalType = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            
            System.out.println("Enter service country: ");
            String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
            
            if(animalType.equalsIgnoreCase("dog")) {
                for(Dog dog: dogList) {
                    if(dog.getInServiceLocation().equals(inServiceCountry)) {
                        //update the reserved attribute
                        dog.setReserved(true);
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
            else if(animalType.equalsIgnoreCase("monkey")) {
                for(Monkey monkey: monkeyList) {
                    if(monkey.getInServiceLocation().equals(inServiceCountry)) {
                        //update the reserved attribute
                        monkey.setReserved(true);
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No animals of that type and location are available.");
                return;
            }
            
        }

        // Complete printAnimals
        // Include the animal name, status, acquisition country and if the animal is reserved.
    // Remember that this method connects to three different menu items.
        // The printAnimals() method has three different outputs
        // based on the listType parameter
        // dog - prints the list of dogs
        // monkey - prints the list of monkeys
        // available - prints a combined list of all animals that are
        // fully trained ("in service") but not reserved 
    // Remember that you only have to fully implement ONE of these lists. 
    // The other lists can have a print statement saying "This option needs to be implemented".
    // To score "exemplary" you must correctly implement the "available" list.
        public static void printAnimals() {
            if(userInput.equals("4")) {
                System.out.println(dogList);
                return;
                
        }
        else if (userInput.equals("5")) {
            System.out.println(monkeyList);
            return;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: `String userInput;` is local to the `main` method.  It can not be accessed in `printAnimals`. This code should not compile.

Comment: Then how can I get it too

Comment: Your `userInput` variable is defined in `main()`, it is not accessible by `printAnimals`. Add parameter to it: `public static void printAnimals(String userInput)`. Also make sure you always call `printAnimals` with `userInput` argument.

Comment: Here are a few hints for you.  *methods* should do one thing only.  The amount of code should fit on your screen.  *writing code* write a little code, compile soon. do not write a whole hunk of code then compile.

Comment: you seem to be missing quite some break statements

Comment: Another observation: the loop checking for the dog already being present should ideally happen right after entering the dog's name. No need to let the user enter all the data and then tell them it was all in vain. Also, the input check on reservation status (i.e. the condition producing "Re-input reservation status.") should be in a separate while-loop as you'd want to continue until either "true" or "false" have been entered - doing this in a loop iterating over the dogs in the system doesn't make any sense.